# Save the words from a text file to two tables in c

Tags: c, file

I have a text file which has two words per line, in every line, and i would like to read it and save the first word of each line in a table of the type first[numberoflinesinfile][maxcharacterperword] and the second one in a similar table. Where each entrie of the tables is a character.

Comment: Read a line. find the split. write to two files. Ten minutes. [hint:dont use `while ( !feof(fp))` ] BTW: how long are the lines? Is there a maximum line length?

Comment: In python i would just use the split function, but i wasn't able to find a function like that in c. Yeah, each word has a maximum lenght of 8, so 16 plus the space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A pretty simple solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME "myFile.txt"

int main () {

    // Open file for reading:
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");

    // Some counters:
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    // Two dimensional arrays: 
    char first[10][30];
    char second[10][30];

    // Loop through file: 
    while ( fscanf(file, "%s", first[i]) != EOF) {
        fscanf(file, "%s", second[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for (j = 0 ; j < i ; j++ ) {
        printf("first@%d: %s - ", j, first[j] );
        printf("second@%d: %s\n", j, second[j] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
these are
some words
to put
into a
matrix for
some fun
```

**Output:**

```
% ./a.out
first@0: these - second@0: are
first@1: some - second@1: words
first@2: to - second@2: put
first@3: into - second@3: a
first@4: matrix - second@4: for
first@5: some - second@5: fun
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT, this is exactly what i needed, but i was using a more complex away, this is much better. Can i ask you another question? How would you do it if you wanted to save all the words of a file in one table just like the above? In that file there can be blank lines, lines with 1, 2, 3, 4...etc, words

Comment: Forget it, it was easy after all